# How to mock data for HttpContext NUnit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq, nullreferenceexception

I have written a test class for my controller class using NUnit and Moq framework.My classes are following

```
  public class ClientTypeController : BaseController
  {
    IClientTypeService clientTypeService;
    IClientTypeAudService clientTypeAudService;
    IClientTypeHisService clientTypeHisService;
    IUserAccountService userAccountService;
    System.Web.HttpResponseBase _responceBase;

    public ClientTypeController()
    {

    }

    public ClientTypeController(IClientTypeService _IClientTypeService, IClientTypeAudService _IClientTypeAudService,
        IClientTypeHisService _IClientTypeHisService,IUserAccountService 
                                                              _IUserAccountService)
    {
        clientTypeService = _IClientTypeService;
        clientTypeAudService = _IClientTypeAudService;
        clientTypeHisService = _IClientTypeHisService;
        userAccountService = _IUserAccountService;
    }
    public ClientTypeController(IClientTypeAudService _clientTypeAudService, 
                             System.Web.HttpResponseBase responceBas)
    {
        clientTypeAudService = _clientTypeAudService;
        this._responceBase = responceBas;
    }
     ......
      .....
```

And my test class for the above given controller class,

```
  public class ClientTypeControllerTest 
  {
    private Mock<IClientTypeService> _clientTypeServiceMock;
    private Mock<IClientTypeAudService> _clientTypeAudServiceMock;
    private Mock<IClientTypeHisService> _clientTypeHisServiceMock;
    private Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> _sessionMock;
    private Mock<HttpResponseBase> _httpresponceMock;
    private Mock<IUserAccountService> _userAccountService;

    ClientTypeController objClientTypeController;
    protected Users LoggedInUser { get; set; }
    List<ClientTypeAud> lists;


    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        _clientTypeServiceMock = new Mock<IClientTypeService>();
        _clientTypeAudServiceMock = new Mock<IClientTypeAudService>();
        _clientTypeHisServiceMock = new Mock<IClientTypeHisService>();
        _userAccountService = new Mock<IUserAccountService>();
        _sessionMock = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        _httpresponceMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var ctrlContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        _sessionMock.SetupGet(s => s["LOGGED_IN_USER"]).Returns(users);
        ctrlContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(_sessionMock.Object);

    }



    [Test]
    public void Show_AllClientTypeRecords_InGridView_UnitTest()
    {
         lists = new List<ClientTypeAud>()  {
         new ClientTypeAud() { Id = 1, CTypeName = "INR", CompanyId = 1, Active = "Y" },
         new ClientTypeAud() { Id = 1, CTypeName = "ABC", CompanyId = 1, Active = "Y" },
         new ClientTypeAud() { Id = 1, CTypeName = "AVM", CompanyId = 1, Active = "Y" }
       };

        _clientTypeAudServiceMock.Setup(x => x.All()).Returns(lists.AsQueryable());
        objClientTypeController = new ClientTypeController(_clientTypeServiceMock.Object, 
                      _clientTypeAudServiceMock.Object, _clientTypeHisServiceMock.Object, 
                                                           _userAccountService.Object);

    var result = objClientTypeController.GridData("", "asc", 1, 1) as JsonResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data);
    }
  }
```

And my BaseController class is ,

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
  {
    public SessionProvider SessionProvider;
    protected Users LoggedInUser { get; set; }

    public string actionName { get; set; }        
    protected string controllerName { get; set; }
    protected string area { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        actionName = 
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        controllerName = 
          System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.
                                                    GetRequiredString("controller");
        SessionProvider = new SessionProvider(Session);
        LoginMethod();            
        ViewBag.Menu = BuildMenu();

  }
 ......
 ......
```

When I run my test class using NUnit then it shows Nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code  on

```
  actionName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.
                                 RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

This is in my BaseControllerClass. So I don't know how to Moq the data for HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.so please Can anyone please help to find the solution

Comment: You have complicated things by using HttpContext into constructor. Normally mocked context is initialized after controller object is created i.e. ctor is executed. Controller.Context = mockedContext. Can you refactor your code?

Comment: Can you give sample code for it ? I tried it in a lot of ways but I can't find the solution, So please if you can help then help me.

Comment: I would be happy to help but not sure I can. Code sample to achieve what? You know your code so you can only do it. You will have to determine how you can postpone using HttpContext at later stage. One option is to define a method in base controller and call when you need that data.

Comment: And just as I noticed, no offense, but I see multiple issue in your code you pasted above. You are doing hell lot of stuff in BaseController CTOR. You should not.

Comment: I did something like this,_httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")).Returns(baseController.methodforRouteData);   But it shows NotSupportedException

Comment: Still i can't find the answer.please anybody help

Answer (score 2):

You should create wrapper utility for handling the HttpContext.

This wrapper should implement an interface and in your UT you should mock that call (you can use Rhino Mocks).